# Workspace.ComposeDocument and QueryOpen and PostOpen events

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm using the following code to create a document in an action on another form:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim NewItemDoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim ParentUNID As String

    ParentUNID = ws.CurrentDocument.Document.UNID(0)

    Set NewItemDoc = ws.ComposeDocument("","","Item")

    Call NewItemDoc.Document.ReplaceItemValue("ParentUNID", ParentUNID)
End Sub
```

I have code in the `Item` form's `QueryOpen` and `PostOpen` event handlers, however they are not running at all. When i used the `@Command([Compose])` there were called.

When debugging lotusscript it doesn't step through those event handlers.

How do i get the equivalent in lotusscript?
i.e. How do i get the `QueryOpen` and `PostOpen` events to trigger?

Comment: I just ran a quick test adding a Msgbox statement to each handler and they do get called.

Comment: They should run, what code do you have in the `QueryOpen`?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, the code was running, but i'd made a mistake. The reason i didn't catch is straight away was that when debugging locusscript, it doesn't step through the event's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two things with your experience on this.

Use "option declare", religiously, and always, (always) include Error trapping in your subs, functions and UI events. A real time saver. Using your code sample, the classic bit of code I use for UI error handling is this

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    on error goto errHandle
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim NewItemDoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim ParentUNID As String

    ParentUNID = ws.CurrentDocument.Document.UNID(0)

    Set NewItemDoc = ws.ComposeDocument("","","Item")

    Call NewItemDoc.Document.ReplaceItemValue("ParentUNID", ParentUNID)
    Exit Sub 
  errhandle:
    MessageBox Lsi_info(2) + " : " + Str(Err) + " - " + Error(Err) + ", at line " + Str(Erl)
    Exit Sub 
End Sub
```

you can choose to use print statements or something more sophisticated to log the error as well. Indispensable. [LSI_Info function](http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20021021230944.html) (even more info [here](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/archive/20040427-1043) to) has been around for some time and has never been an issue for me to use.

Secondly, when you launch a new form from LotusScript, the LotusScript debugger does not run with the new form. This is because the LotusScript debugger only runs on one "UI process thread" at a time, launching a new UI form, (not a dialogue box), runs a new instance. I use the term "process thread" pretty loosely here, because I'm trying to make the distinction that UI forms are independent of each other and do not interact, therefore the debugger does not follow into the new form.

Unlike the behaviour with a dialog box, which is modal. The debugger won't follow into a dialogbox either, (remember you'll get that warning message), and when you close the form, the debugger will return to the originating form because it's directly linked to the originating UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of what's going on behind the scenes. I already use `option explicit` (sounds more exciting than `option declare`!). The error logging info helps too.

Comment: Ahh.. yes.. you can use "explicit" to. I am a bit old school and was weaned on "option declare"..LOL